# Value in Console Not Updating in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pusher

I have a value that when updated in the console is not being reflected in my HTML.

I have implemented a presence channel using Pusher that requires no authentication.

```
class PusherController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: :auth
  def auth
    response = Pusher['presence-channel'].authenticate( params[:socket_id], { user_id: params[:socket_id] } )
    render :json => response
  end
end


  var pusher = new Pusher('7a543339502a4a02');
  var presenceChannel = pusher.subscribe('presence-channel')
  presenceChannel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members){
      userCount = members.count
      document.getElementById('userCount').innerHTML = userCount;
  });
```

When I open two browsers, the first one's HTML displays 1, while entering in Dev Tools `presenceChannel.members.count`  returns 2.

Why are the changes not being reflected in my HTML, and how do I reflect them in my HTML?

Comment: What is output to the browser console? Do you have any output from setting [`Pusher.log`](https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging)?

Comment: `@leggetter Pusher.log = function(members){ `  returns `undefined`

Comment: So the websocket is open and authenticated and the event is being sent but the function returns the value as undefined

Comment: The section on "Enable JavaScript Logging" in the docs is the part I was referring to. See https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging